# Rails 4 create new Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few questions about how to add a Tag to a users account:

Here is the User Model in relation to Tags

```
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

Here is the Tag Model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :unread_count, :user_feeds

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :feeds, through: :taggings
end
```

And the Tagging Model:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :feed
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm at a point in the script where I have the current user object `@user` and I need to simply create a tag named "Mailbox" if it does not exist.  I have tried a few create methods, and got expected object errors.

If anyone can help explain how to work with these models I would appreciate it.

Comment: @user.tags << Tag.new(:name => "Mailbox") you probably want check that the tag does not already exist first

Comment: So no save method or anything?

Comment: Try it and watch the sql generated in the log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A legit way to do this is to

```
@user.tags.create(name: "Mailbox")
```

If you want to check if it exists first, the rails 4 way is to:

```
@user.tags.find_or_create_by(name: "Mailbox")
```

Comment if you have any more question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `<<` method which the `has_many` association automatically adds:

```
@user.tags << Tag.find_or_create_by(name:'Mailbox')
```

Or, the rails 3 way:

```
@user.tags << Tag.where(name:'Mailbox').first_or_create!(name:'Mailbox')
# Or, as the << method automatically saves new objects
@user.tags << Tag.where(name:'Mailbox').first_or_initialize(name:'Mailbox')
```